# Canvas recording and on Mac

Tags: software-recommendation, mac, painting

I did some painting on iPad, in Procreate. Now I am moving to Mac with Wacom Intuos Pro. I am playing with Photoshop, Pixelmator and Sketchbook.

I am looking for some plug-in or maybe completely another painting app, with the canvas recording.

In this very moment Screenflow is encoding my last painting and it says it will take more than hour. That's something I want to avoid. Back on my iPad there was not such big waitings during painting(recording) or during video export.

I ideally want to record the whole canvas, not just the window in which i zoom, rotate, etc.

[This is the kind of recording i mean.](http://vimeo.com/119014908) I zoomed the canvas number of times and did undos. In the resulting video there are only the changes i actually made to canvas. No tool selections, no zooming.

Better explanation may be [Article about Procreate's recording](http://appleinsider.com/articles/13/08/20/ipad-illustration-app-procreate-gets-canvas-recording-with-full-hd-video-playback-in-update)

So... How can I achieve that on Mac?

Comment: I'm not certain what you are looking for exists for the Mac. There's SnapzProx, Screenflow, Camtasia, etc. They'll all record a screen or window, but I'm unaware of *anything* that will target *only* the canvas automatically. The iPad is different in that there is no "cursor" so it merely records touch actions.

Comment: https://vimeo.com/119014908 — this is the kind of recording i mean. I zoomed the canvas number of times and did undos. In the resulting video there are only the changes i actually made to canvas. No tool selections, no zooming. And then there is also the performance. http://appleinsider.com/articles/13/08/20/ipad-illustration-app-procreate-gets-canvas-recording-with-full-hd-video-playback-in-update . I think Sketchbook had this feature. BTW now i use Screenflow but it records whole screen and the encoding takes "ages".

Comment: I think you're kind of stuck because you want to remove the cursor. As far as I'm aware only ScreenFlow or Camtasia has that ability. And I don't think there's a way to get around the performance issue -- I could be wrong, but I don't think what you want exists really.

Comment: The goal is not removing cursor. You still think about it as screen recording. I want recording of changes on canvas.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the more current OSX, Quicktime Player has a built in utility to record your screen (screencast). Or you should be able to download it for free (I think) as well. I think only the new QTP (dark blue logo) has this function. Not sure how long it takes to encode the video though. Once you click the red button, you have the option to record the entire screen, or drag the area (your canvas) you want to record. This could help reduce file size -> encoding time drastically.

If QTP turns out to also take time to encode, I suggest breaking your painting session into maybe 15 minutes. Stop/pause so QTP can encode in the background while you start a new recording session. When it comes to video encoding, it all comes down if your computer has the necessary hardware to handle it. I believe any software will take time to encode the longer you record, especially if you want it to be high quality.

Remember that any app that records your screen on iPad would almost certainly record it at a lower resolution (hence the shorter wait time).

[image: how to activate new screen recording]
[image: screen recording options]

Comment: Thank you for tip. I knew about screen recording in QTP, but as I already tried it before, it just transfers the CPU consumption in the recording part (but the saving of final video file is almost instant).  So it consumes resources which could utilize the painting app. I did not mentioned that explicitly, in question. I ideally want to record the whole canvas, not just the window in which i zoom, rotate, etc.

Comment: One think came to my mind. When recording via QTP it takes lot of CPU. Isn't there some hidden setting to delegate that to graphic card?

Comment: @Mailo i think if you have dedicated graphic cards, the computer will use it automatically. Another thing you might look into is to increase system memory cache. That might help. Otherwise, like I said, you'll need a good computer setup.